# Alternate Tree implementation

Tags: tree, comparative-review, scala

I am trying to implement algorithms related to trees in Scala. I have dabbled with the following implementations of a tree. Are there any pros and cons of preferring the non-`Option` related implementation over the one that uses `Option`?

Implementation with `Option`:

```
  sealed trait Node {
    val label: Int
  }
  case class LeafNode(override val label: Int) extends Node
  case class BranchNode(override val label: Int, left: Option[Node], right: Option[Node]) extends Node

  def inorderTraversal(aTree: Option[Node]): List[Int] = {
    def helper(aTree: Option[Node], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = aTree match {
      case None => acc
      case Some(LeafNode(label)) => helper(None, label :: acc)
      case Some(BranchNode(label, left, right)) => helper(left, acc) ++ helper(None, label :: acc) ++ helper(right, acc)
    }
    helper(aTree, List.empty[Int])
  }
```

Implementation without `Option`:

```
  sealed trait Tree {
    def value: Int
    def left: Tree
    def right: Tree
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def inorder(acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      if (isEmpty) acc else {
        left.inorder(acc) ++ List(value) ++ right.inorder(acc)
      }
    }
  }

  case object Leaf extends Tree {
    override def value = throw new IllegalArgumentException
    override def left = throw new IllegalArgumentException
    override def right = throw new IllegalArgumentException
    override def isEmpty = true
  }

  case class Branch(override val value: Int, left: Tree=Leaf, right: Tree=Leaf) extends Tree {
    override def isEmpty = false
  }
```

The `Option` related implementation leads to a lot of pattern matching code, sometimes multiple `case` statements. Whereas with the non-`Option` method I can get by using the `isEmpty` check. I am biased towards the non-`Option` method because the code appears simpler to follow.

Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like either implementation, but since you asked, the first one is the least bad since it makes better use of case classes. And that brings me to my first point,

## You need to make use of case classes (better)

And it all starts with the first thing you did in your code. Because you did this:

```
sealed trait Node {
   val label: Int
}
```

You just automatically eliminated the ability to create empty trees due to the fact that every tree now has to contain an item. This puts you in a bad position because as you have noticed, you now have no choice but to resort to Options. Don't get me wrong, Option monads are great but when used in such a manner it does them no justice.

Anyways, I suggest removing the `val label: Int` and just having an empty sealed trait.

```
sealed trait Node {}
```

Then you can also remove the `override` from your other classes:

```
case class LeafNode(label: Int) extends Node
case class BranchNode(label: Int, left: Option[Node], right: Option[Node]) extends Node
```

Still looks pretty bad, but we can fix that.

## Case Objects are still a thing

From the above use of `Option`, it would seem that you are trying to say that a BranchNode can *sometimes* contain a node and other times, contain *nothing*. In that case, let's create a better representation of `"Nothing"` by making use of case objects:

```
case object EmptyNode extends Node
```

**Aha!** *you say*

**Mhm** *I reply*

Since we now have a case object to represent the Empty state of a tree, let's reconstruct our tree now

```
case object EmptyNode extends Node
case class LeafNode(label: Int) extends Node
case class BranchNode(label: Int, left: Node, right: Node) extends Node
```

And there you go, a perfect recipe for great pattern matching.

---

With this in order, we can now reconstruct the traversal method. Note you have two options with this, either create an implicit class which implements the traversal method and allows you to do `tree.inorderTraversal` or create a method which takes the tree as you have already done. For this demonstration, I will opt for the implicit class option:

```
implicit class InorderTraversable(val aTree: Node) extends AnyVal {
    def inorderTraversal: List[Int] = aTree match {
        case EmptyNode => List()
        case LeafNode(item) => List(item)
        case BranchNode(item, left, right) => (left.inorderTraversal :+ item) ++ right.inorderTraversal
    }
}
```

### Other statements

- Avoid nesting functions if you can
- [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Try.html) to throw less exceptions
- Use pattern matching to your full advantage. Read more [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-match-expression-like-switch-statement)

## Putting it all together:

```
package com.codereview

sealed trait Node {}
case object EmptyNode extends Node
case class LeafNode(label: Int) extends Node
case class BranchNode(label: Int, left: Node, right: Node) extends Node

object Main extends App {
    implicit class InorderTraversable(val aTree: Node) extends AnyVal {
        def inorderTraversal: List[Int] = aTree match {
            case EmptyNode => List()
            case LeafNode(item) => List(item)
            case BranchNode(item, left, right) => (left.inorderTraversal :+ item) ++ right.inorderTraversal
        }
    }

    val tree =
    BranchNode(1,
        BranchNode(2,
            BranchNode(3, 
                BranchNode(4, LeafNode(6), LeafNode(5)),
                BranchNode(7, LeafNode(8), EmptyNode)),LeafNode(9)), LeafNode(10))

    println(tree.inorderTraversal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also incline to the non-`Option` implementation. I tried to ask myself what value does `Option` bring to the actual implementation?

- Having the branches optional doesn't help me when building the API or even using the tree: I still have to check if they're empty or not.
- The code indeed is less readable and doesn't signal an exception
- The `Node` should describe exactly an abstract node: something that has a value (label) and that might link to other nodes.
- The `Leaf` class should throw an exception when its left / right branches are accessed - after all, this is how `Option` deals with `#get` calls on a `None`.

Furthermore, you can provide an easy way to to convert a node / tree into an `Option`:

```scala
sealed trait BTree[+T] {
  def value: T
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def toOption: Option[T] = if (this.isEmpty) None else Some(value)
}
```

Finally, as you've already pointed out the code is much readable if you pick the non-option implementation. I've omitted the rest of the code because is very much like yours except for the generic type :)